# Finding the support of transformations of random variables

Tags: random-variable, distributions

Let $X, Y \sim iid U(0,1)$ and $c_1, c_2 \in \mathbb{R}$. In the linear combination $Z = c_1X+c_2Y$, we know that the probability density function of $Z$ depends on the relationships of $c_1$ and $c_2$.

For example, when $c_1 > c_2 > 0$, then the pdf of $Z$ is given by

$$ f(z) = \mathbf{1}_{0 \leq z \leq c_2} \dfrac{z}{c_1c_2} +\mathbf{1}_{c_2\leq z \leq c_1} \dfrac{c_2}{c_1c_2} + \mathbf{1}_{c_1 \leq z \leq c_1+c_2} \dfrac{c_1+c_2-z}{c_1c_2}.$$

The range of the support in this case is: $[0, c_1+c_2]$.

If $c_1 >0$ but $c_2<0$, then the support would be $[-c_2,c_1]$.

By symmetry, if $c_1 < c_2 < 0$ then the support would be $[-(c_1 + c_2),0]$.

I'm not really concerned about the pdf, just the support. Lastly, what will happen to the support of more complicated transformations like: support for pdf of $\sqrt{Z^2 -1}$ and $Z + \sqrt{Z^2 - 1}$? Is there a quick way to find out?

I am also interested in the supports so that the last two transformations are real or complex.

Your insights are appreciated.

Comment: I am not sure I buy this whole $c_{1} > c_{2} > 0$ thing, since $X$ and $Y$ are both $\sim\text{i.i.d.}\mathcal{U}(0,1)$, this makes the ordering of $c_{1}$ and $c_{2}$ arbitrary, right? So instead of $c_{1} > c_{2} > 0$, don't you mean $c_{1} > 0$ *and* $c_{2} > 0$? Same for the $<0$ case.

Comment: Yes, ordering wouldn't matter.

Comment: Also "If $c_1 >0$ but $c_2<0$, then the support would be $[-c_2,c_1]$." Should be "If $c_1 >0$ but $c_2<0$, then the support would be $[\mathbf{c_2},c_1]$," since $c_{2} \times -1 > 0$ in that case, but the support should *span* 0. Same thing on the following line: the support should just be "$[(c_{1}+c_{2}),0]$," with no negative sign.

Comment: In the last part, are you asking about cases where $T(Z)$ (e.g. $T(Z)=\sqrt{Z^2-1}\,$) is monotonic, or just defined everywhere in the domain of $Z$, or are you asking about cases where the transformation may not even be defined? (Also, please address Alexis' last comment; your question still has errors.)

Answer (score 1):

$\DeclareMathOperator{\support}{support}$The general question here is a very hard problem, for the following reason.

Let $f(x_1, \dots, x_n)$ be any function, and let $X_1, \dots, X_n$ be Gaussian random variables. Then the r.v. $f(X_1, \dots, X_n)$ has support at 0 if and only if the equation $f(x_1, \dots, x_n) = 0$ has real-valued solutions. So determining the support of a function of random variables is *at least* as hard as finding the zeros of the relevant functions. But for even fairly simple classes of functional expressions, finding their zeros is *undecidable* (there is no algorithm!) For instance, by [Richardson's Theorem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/RichardsonsTheorem.html), even if $f$ is restricted to be a function of one argument using the constants $\pi$ and $\ln 2$, addition, multiplication, and the functions $\sin, \exp$ and absolute value--the question of whether $f(X)$ has support at 0 is in general undecidable.

You can make some progress on specific sub-cases. For instance, if $X$ has support on $[a, b]$ and $f$ is continuous and monotone increasing in that range, then $f(X)$ has support on $[f(a_X), f(b)]$.

Similarly, if the random variables $X$ and $Y$ have *joint* support on the entire rectangle $[a_X, b_X] \times [a_Y, b_Y]$, and $f$ is a continuous function of two arguments, monotone increasing in both on that rectangle, then $f(X, Y)$ has support on $[f(a_X, a_Y), f(b_X, b_Y)]$ (and there are similar versions if $f$ is monotone decreasing in one or both arguments instead).

Finally, to tackle non-monotone functions of random variables, you can chop up their domain into rectangular chunks where they *are* monotone, and then calculate the support of the function *conditional* on the arguments lying within that chunk, and then take the union of those supports at the end: for instance, $\support(X^2) = \support(X^2 \mid X \ge 0) \cup \support(X^2 \mid X \le 0)$. But the process of conditioning in this way can get very thorny if there are lots of sub-expressions and dependence between the arguments.

Clever application of the above three principles will probably get you fairly far, but there's no general answer for arbitrary functions.

Comment: Could you provide the definition you are using of "support"? You seem to equate it to the range of the random variable (as a measurable function $X:\Omega\to\mathbb{R}$), whereas [the appropriate definition of support](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_distribution#Basic_terms) in this context involves the probability distribution and is not necessarily the same thing.

Comment: @whuber: no, sorry, I'm just using $\min$ in a perhaps non-standard way (meaning "the minimum value taken on by $A$ with probability > 0" rather than the minimum of the pdf or something). Does that clarify things? Your comment is vague enough that I'm having a hard time figuring out whether I'm missing something or just didn't explain myself well.

Comment: (It's true that I omitted some corner cases here, like variables with gaps in the middle of their support or what happens when your variables have support on all of $\mathbb{R}$, but I don't think that complicates things terribly.)

Comment: The discussion of Diophantine equations seems not to pay any attention to the underlying probability distribution--that's confusing. Furthermore, your algorithm is not generally correct. For instance, suppose the supports of $A$ and $B$ are $[-101,-100]\cup[100,101]$.  Then the support of $A+B$ is quite a bit smaller than the value $[-202,202]$ given by your algorithm!

Comment: @whuber: (1) it does mention the probability distribution--the underlying probability distribution of the $X_i$ needs to have support along the entire real line. Other than that it doesn't matter. I can flesh out the argument if you're still confused. (2) As I mentioned in my comment *right above* yours, I omitted the case of variables with non-convex support. I'll edit in the extra condition this entails (continuous functions and support equal to an interval).

Comment: Augh, no, it's still not right because you can have cancellation if the same variable appears more than once.

Comment: @whuber: thanks for pointing out the errors. I've removed it from the answer, leaving only arguments for why this is a hard problem (undecidable in general) and some general heuristics.